# SQL ODBC adapter out of memory exception

Tags: c#, sql, odbc, out-of-memory, sqldataadapter

I am connecting and receiving data from IBM's I Series AS400 database, using odbc adapters and dataset.

I have an odbc connection like given below:

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn);           // Set Active Query
OdbcDataAdapter rt = new OdbcDataAdapter(queryString, conn);    // Active Data Transfer
DataSet ds = new DataSet();                                     // Create DataSet
rt.SelectCommand.CommandTimeout = 180;                          // Set Command Timeout
rt.Fill(ds);                                                    // Transfer All Data
var reader = ds.CreateDataReader();                             // Create Reader
reader.Read();                                                  // Read
while (reader.Read()) { ... }
```

and it strangely gives the `System.OutOfMemoryException` on line `rt.Fill(ds);`

If there are 1billion rows with 130 columns would it cause this error?

How can i avoid this error and recieve the data i want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there are 1billion rows with 130 columns would it cause this error?

That seems like a lot of data and would likely cause the error.

> How can i avoid this error and recieve the data i want?

You should use the `DataReader` directly, bypassing the `DataSet`. If you do this, the `DataReader` will load only one row of data, only getting the next row when you call `Read`.

```
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(queryString, conn); // Set Active Query
conn.Open();                          // You may not need this if already open
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();     // Create Reader
while (reader.Read()) { ... }         // Process records, one at a time
reader.Close();                       // Close Reader after use
```

More info:

[OdbcDataReader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcdatareader.aspx) at MSDN

[Contrasting the ADO.NET DataReader and DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188717.aspx)